# How to achive react-native-raw-bottom-sheet with black transparent while bottom sheet is opened?

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I am using react-native-raw-bottom-sheet in react native application which black transparent view while opening the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RBSheet
  ref={refRBSheet}
  closeOnDragDown={true}
  closeOnPressMask={true}
  customStyles={{
    wrapper: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.6)',
    },
    draggableIcon: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  }}>
```

Comment: use:
 wrapper: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.6)',
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please review this package, https://github.com/nomi9995/react-native-bottomsheet-reanimated

This package might be helpful for you.

Regards,
Muhammad Asad

P.S. I am one of the contributors in this package, we are publishing a new release in a couple of hours.